# Validation of parameters in Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson

I am developing a plugin that accepts some values from the user. I would like to validate the values user is providing when user is saving those values(not when the plugin is executing). I have already tried FormValidation using doCheckXYZ(), but while it shows the error message, it doesn't stop the user from saving those incorrect values. Also it doesn't seem to work with Pipelines. Is there any other way?

Comment: Could you just throw an exception?

Comment: @ShaneBishop Do you mean inside the doCheckXYZ method? I tried that. While it doesn't allow the user to save the form with incorrect value for freestyle jobs, it seems to have no effect when the plugin is invoked within a Jenkins pipeline.